# ubuntu14.04 buildroot No hash found for gcc

Tags: linux, buildroot

When I want to build a crosscompiler for mips on ubuntu14, after build downloading the gcc, an error occurred:

ERROR:

> No hash found for gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2

ubuntu14.04   gcc version 4.9.4

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indicate which Buildroot version you're using, and which Buildroot configuration. So there's no way this question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more details about buildroot and your config file.

Although, this error is trapped by check-hash.sh script
in bath >> /buildroot/support/download/

and that happens commonly because of broken symbolic link between this to files

```
**/buildroot/package/gcc/gcc.hash
/buildroot/package/gcc/gcc-initial/gcc-initial.hash**
```

THE solution is to fix this broken symlink:

> First delete gcc-initial.hash
> Run: **sudo ln -s /home/joe/Build/buildroot/package/gcc/gcc.hash gcc-initial.hash**

Same solution fixes "  NO hash error " for any different package

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you haven't fixed this by now, but for those coming in off search engines:

Ensure `core.symlinks=true` in your Git repo config. You may have checked out the symlinks within the repo as plain text files, which will break all kinds of things.